# Top Bar on Two Screens: 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I have a dual screen set up. I'd like to see the top bar on both screens. How do I make this occur?

Thanks!

Comment: It occurs automatically with mirrored screens.

Comment: I assume that mirrored screens is two screens showing the same thing? I don't have this for my set up. I have 2 screens that can show different things.

Comment: There are always two options: Mirrored or extended. With extended the secondary monitor just extends the area of the primary. Launcher and "top bar" can be set to one or the other.

Comment: Ah, then what I mean is as follows: I'd like two copies of the top bar on the extended setting.

Comment: And that is exactly what I'm not sure is possible with extended desktop.

Comment: I don't have two screens, so I cannot test; but, did you try the **Dash to panel** extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gnome Shell extension [Multi Monitors Add-On by spin83](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/) is designed to do what you are looking after. Install it using the command `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-multimonitors` then enable it using the "Extensions" tool (not installed by default, install it using `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs`. Alternatively, install it using the [Gnome Shell Extensions website](https://extensions.gnome.org/).